# Constructing a method to search a binary tree

Tags: java, methods, parameters, tree, binary-search-tree

I have constructed a binary search tree that will sort people based on their name, the code for this is:

code for the class Person:

```
package Tree;

public class Person {
private int age;
private String name;
private String gender;

public Person( String name, String gender,int age) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person [age=" + age + ", name=" + name + ", gender="
            + gender + "]";
}
}
```

the search tree code is:

```
package Tree;

public class BinarySearchPerson {

private boolean empty;
private Person person;
private BinarySearchPerson left;
private BinarySearchPerson right;

public BinarySearchPerson(Person person, BinarySearchPerson left,
        BinarySearchPerson right) {
    this.empty = false;
    this.person = person;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
}

public BinarySearchPerson() {
    this.empty = true;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return empty;
}

public Person getPerson() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Trying to access root of an empty tree");
    }
    return person;
}

public void setPerson(Person person) {
    this.person = person;
}


public BinarySearchPerson getLeft() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                                        "Trying to access subtree of an empty tree");
    }
    return left;
}


public void setLeft(BinarySearchPerson left) {
    this.left = left;
}


/**
 * gets the right subtree of this node
 */
public BinarySearchPerson getRight() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                                        "Trying to access subtree of an empty tree");
    }
    return right;
}


public void setRight(BinarySearchPerson right) {
    this.right = right;
}



public static BinarySearchPerson insert(Person person, BinarySearchPerson bt){
    int n = person.getName().compareTo(bt.getPerson().getName());


    if (n<0){
        if(bt.getLeft().isEmpty() == true){
             BinarySearchPerson newLeft = new BinarySearchPerson(person,new BinarySearchPerson(),new BinarySearchPerson());
             bt.setLeft(newLeft);
             return bt;
        }
        else{
            insert(person, bt.getLeft());
            return bt;

        }
    }

    if (n>0){
        if(bt.getRight().isEmpty() == true){
             BinarySearchPerson newRight = new BinarySearchPerson(person,new BinarySearchPerson(),new BinarySearchPerson());
             bt.setRight(newRight);
             return bt;
        }
        else{
            insert(person, bt.getRight());
            return bt;
        }
    }
    else return bt;


}


public static int lookupAge(String name) {
    Person person = 
    if (name.compareTo(person.getName())==0){
        return person.getAge();
    }
    else return -1;

}




}
```

and the code i have been using to test it with:

```
package Tree;

public class TreeTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person p = new Person("John", "M",32);
    Person p1 = new Person("Alex", "M",15);   
    Person p2 = new Person("Tom", "M",24);   
    Person p3 = new Person("Bill", "M",23);  
    Person p4 = new Person ("Jackson", "F", 50);  

    BinarySearchPerson bt = new BinarySearchPerson(p,new BinarySearchPerson(),new BinarySearchPerson());
    BinarySearchPerson bt1 = BinarySearchPerson.insert(p1, bt);
    BinarySearchPerson bt2 = BinarySearchPerson.insert(p2, bt1);
    BinarySearchPerson bt3 = BinarySearchPerson.insert(p3, bt2);
    BinarySearchPerson bt4 = BinarySearchPerson.insert(p4, bt3);
    System.out.println("alex".compareTo("john"));

    System.out.println(bt4.getLeft().getRight().getRight().getPerson().getName());


}

}
```

The method works and sorts the names out well. What I am trying to do now is create a new method

lookupAge(String name);

that can be used to search the tree for a person's name. I have a rough idea of how to do this but i am struggling with the syntax for creating this method. The method must be able to be called like:

```
bt.lookupAge("Tom");
```

and that should return 24, which is Tom's age.

I need to look through the tree to find tom but the method only has parameter name so i don't know how to refer to the tree bt. I have never made a method this way before, only by including all the parameters that i need to use. I would be ok making it if it was

```
lookupAge(String Name, BinarySearchPerson bt);
```

but i can't include the tree as a parameter.

any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your method in the BinarySearchPerson class  so that it looks something like

```
public int lookupAge(String name) {...
```

Once written, if someone calls the method like in your example, `bt.lookupAge("Tom")`, the 'this' parameter will refer to `bt`.  You'll then compare `this.person.getName()` to name and either return this.person.getAge(), or return something like `this.lookupAge(getRight().getPerson().getName())`